# XPath selector working on chrome dev tool but not with php domXpath why is it

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

Trying to scrape a page using xpath and php domxpath, the xpath expression is pulling data in chrome dev tool, but it returns empty result on php code, Here is the [sample page](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/8120340078)

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTMLFile($file);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);    

    $nodes = $xpath->query('//*[@id="detail_bullets_id"]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/ul/li');
```

I tried saving entire file as html file and did xpath query on that. Can someone help ? Thanks.

Comment: There's no `<tbody>` in the HTML. The browser is adding that when it parses it.

Comment: $nodes = $xpath->query('//*[@id="detail_bullets_id"]/table/tr/td/div/ul/li');
Cool ! this works